# Rstudio frequently erroneously displays debug warnings on the left margin

Tags: rstudio

I find that Rstudio frequently will have those debug warnings in the left margin that are wrong.  Usually what I do to get rid of them is to highlight and delete a whole section and then hit undo.  The code comes back and the debug warnings stay away unless I make the wrong change.

It's hard to nail down exactly how to make it reproduceable but generally it complains about either curly braces, parenthesis, or brackets that aren't closed.

Is there a way to make it scan the code more often?  It essentially has the ability to parse the code correctly it just seems that it doesn't parse often enough which causes the erroneous warnings.

I don't want to disable the warnings as they are occasionally helpful, I just want them to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear on what your exact issue is. If unpaired curly braces/ parentheses/ or brackets are the issue....then the simple fix is
goto

> `Tools` tab -- `Global Options` -- `Code` -- Tick mark the option insert matching parenthesis and quotes

This will enable the automatic insertion of parentheses